# Add an updated DBC to docker install

Tags: docker, azerothcore

So I was able to find where to put lua scripts and those are working on the server. However I have a few custom items that one of which is currency which I want in the currency tab. I have updated the DBCs `items.dbc` and `currencytypes.dbc` as necessary. However I can not seem to figure out where to put them so that the server will take them when I update it. Kind of how it was fairly simple with the lua scripts I have made. I have tried several locations with no success and searching in discord yielded one lead however it had the famous "nvm I figured it out" and did not elaborate.

In short, is there are directory I can put them in to be updated similar to how the lua is is put in `\acore-docker-master\scripts\lua\@azerothcore`

I have figured it out after delving more into docker in general. This has been a wonderful way to learn more about docker.

For those that come across this. This was my solution:

in your terminal:

`docker ps` to get your container id

then it was as simple as:

`docker cp [file to copy] [container id]:.\azerothcore\env\dist\data\dbc`

Without the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

For those that come across this. This was my solution:

in your terminal:

`docker ps` to get your container id

then it was as simple as:

`docker cp [file to copy] [container id]:.\azerothcore\env\dist\data\dbc`

Without the brackets.